# Checking the database and redirectering to the particular page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

If the admin login  checked is correct it should redirect to dashboard page, but if admin login is correct or incorrect it is going to dashboard page. If it is incorrect it should go to login page.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
class Validate extends CI_Model
{
    public function checkdatabase()
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        //echo $username;
        $this->load->database();
         $query ="select * from adminlogin where name='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $value = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $value->result();
    return $data;

    }
}
?>
```

Here is the condition in the controller

```
if($value=$this->validate->checkdatabase()){
    redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
    }else{
    $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
```

Comment: Where do you return anything in `checkdatabase()`?

Comment: i updated as return $query; but no use it is going to dashboard page only

Comment: You need to check how many rows are in `$query`. It's only set to false if the query fails, so incorrect details will still end up returning true. Try returning false if `$query` is false, and then returning `mysql_num_rows($query)`

Comment: What does it return when someone with the username of `O'Connor` logs in?

Comment: Sanitize your queries. Use CodeIgniter's input wrapper. `$this->input->post('username');`. You might also want to use their database wrapper.

Comment: Also make sure to escape $_POSt before using it in your query. if $_POST['password'] = `1' or true or '1``; the user gets logged no matter what ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is a fair bit wrong with the way you're doing things, first and foremost in my mind is you're not auto-loading the database library, with just about any CI site you're going to be using that library so often it makes no sense not to have it auto-loading.

Next, as others have said you're not sanitizing the input at all leaving yourself open for injection, and considering it's a login you've left that completely wide open. CI's input wrapper handles that for you, see in the code below.

You're also not checking to see what the return value is, and with logins you always check for a single return.

```
<?php 
class Validate extends CI_Model
{
    public function checkdatabase()
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password'); //and honestly this is taking a plain text password... not a good thing.
        //echo $username;
        $this->load->database();  //again, do this in the autoload.php
         $query ="select * from adminlogin where name='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $value = $this->db->query($query);
    if($value->num_rows()==1)
    {
        $data = $value->result();
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I see after typing this that you've got it working, there are still valid points here you should take into consideration so I'll post it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
`
    $value=$this->validate->checkdatabase();
    if(isset($value)){
        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
`
```

@ [My Code Programs](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/)